# One ASP.NET Web Service Cannot Get User.Identity.Name. The Other Web Service is OK

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I need to convert an old ASP.NET application from Windows-XP era to Windows Server 2022. The program itself works fine when the server part and the client part both run in the same computer. But as soon as I move the server part to Windows Server 2022, I find that one of the web-service cannot retrieve my username using User.Identity.Name. Strangely, another related web-service has NO problem retrieving my username using User.Identity.Name.

Let call the first web-service WebService1 and the second web-service WebService2.

The Authentication settings in IIS of both web-services are these:

- Anonymous Authentication   Disabled
- ASP.NET Impersonation      Disabled
- Forms Authentication       Disabled
- Windows Authentication     Enabled

I want to use Windows Authentication as the way for our users to run the ASP.NET app. Then our users don't need to enter their username or password to run the program.

For now, I am only testing using my user account. I am the local admin of the IIS server. I should have full access rights on it.

So far, I find that both web-services have no problem getting WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name. It always returns 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. That is to be expected. The problem has to do with trying to get access to User.Identity in Session_Start() event handler:
WebService1 will trigger an exception and has this error "Public member 'Identity' on type SecurityIdentifier not found at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(...).
On the other hand, WebService2 will get the correct username, such as 'MyDomain\MyName'

I have tried the most logical thing by force-matching the Web.config of WebService1 in the new web server to match the Web.config in the known-good web server. But I still have the exact same problem.

Unfortunately, I cannot force-match the Web.config of WebService1 in the new web server to match the Web.config of WebService2 because there are too many differences.

So far, the only workaround that I have found is to use either of these workarounds:

- Use My.User.Name. But this only works if I Enable "Anonymous Authentication" for WebService1. Somehow, this triggers Windows Security to prompt me for my password (despite the fact that I have enabled "Windows Authentication"). After I have entered my password, WebService1 can get access my username through My.User.Name.
- Use My.User.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name. This only works if I Disable "Anonymous Authentication" for WebService1. Somehow, this also triggers Windows Security to prompt me for my password (despite the fact that I have enabled "Windows Authentication"). After I have entered my password, WebService1 can get access my username through My.User.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.

There are two problems with either of this workaround though: (1) Windows Security will keep prompting me for a password whenever the program is launched despite the fact that I have chosen the "Remember my credentials" option. Very annoying. (2) I still cannot get access to User.Identity.

This is like that my program cannot use Windows Authentication to get access to WebService1. But it has no problem using Windows Authentication to get access to WebService2.

By the way, I have enabled "Use Windows Authentication" in the Visual Studio 2017 project properties of the EXE client program that we use to get access to the web-services. That is in project properties --> Services --> Enable client application services --> Use Windows Authentication. This means my program is supposed to use Windows Authentication.

My Questions are:

1. Why WebService1 cannot get access to User.Identity when WebService2 can? Their authentication settings in IIS are exactly the same.
2. Why Windows Security prompts me for a password when I enable "Anonymous Authentication" for WebService1 in IIS and in my program?  I thought "Windows Authentication" should have taken care of this. How can I ask it to stop prompting me for a password?
3. Is there another way to force the client part of the program (.EXE) to always use Windows Authentication?
4. Is there a way to test WebService1 to confirm that it is using Windows Authentication? I have tried entering the URL of WebService1 and WebService2 directly in a web browser (to bypass the client part of my program). In both cases, the web browser prompts me for username and password -- act like they don't support Windows Authentication. This cannot be a good test because I am quite sure that Windows Authentication works fine in WebService2.

I have also tried to add the following attribute to the VB code of WebService1:

```
<Authorize> _
```

This requires adding the namespace "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" to the project of WebService1. But I cannot find this namespace in Visual Studio 2017, and I cannot find a way to download the DLL of that namespace either. I am not sure if this is the solution of my problem or not. My C# code of WebService2 doesn't have that Authorize-Attribute, and it works fine. I doubt this will do anything for the VB code of WebService1.

The following are the simplified version of Web.config of WebService1 and WebService2 for your reference.

Web.config of WebService1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" />
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
      <pages validateRequest="false" /> 
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      <identity impersonate="false" />
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false"
         traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
      <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
         sqlConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=;
         Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XYZ;Initial Catalog=ABC;
         Data Source=DAF" cookieless="false" timeout="525600" />
      <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" />
      <httpHandlers>
         <add verb="*" path="GetSessionParam.aspx"
            type="MyApp.Common.SessionStateHandler, MyApp.Common" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <webServices>
         <soapExtensionTypes>
            <add type="MyApp.Common.Compression, MyApp.Common"
               priority="1" group="0" />
         </soapExtensionTypes>
      </webServices>
      <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
   </system.web>
   <appSettings>
      .
      .
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Web.config of WebService2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="log4net"
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
   </configSections>
   <system.web>
      <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
      <identity impersonate="false" />
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false"
         traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
      <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
         sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
         cookieless="false" timeout="1440" />
      <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
      <webServices>
         <soapExtensionTypes>
            <add type="MyApp.Common.Compression, MyApp.Common" priority="1" group="0" />
         </soapExtensionTypes>
      </webServices>
      <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
   </system.web>
   <log4net>
      <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
         .
         .
      </appender>
      <root>
         <level value="INFO" />
         <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      </root>
   </log4net>
   <appSettings>
      .
      .
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have spent more than 1 week trying to figure this out. And all I can come up with are those two workarounds that I don't like.  Please help.  Thanks.

JC_BL

Comment: "an exception and has this error ..." You didn't post the entire exception information.

Comment: I have already mentioned the exact error message in my original message posted above:  Public member 'Identity' on type 'SecurityIdentifier' not found.

Comment: I found that the new IIS server name was not added to the list of intranet web sites in Internet Options for automatic logon.  After the network admin has added the new IIS server to the list, I can enter the URL of the web services to a web browser, and the web browser does NOT prompt me for username and password, and WebService2 works properly (it can get User.Identity.Name).  Unfortunately, WebService1 still cannot get access to User.Identity.Name.  Now, at least, I know that I can enter URL of a web service to a web browser to determine if Windows Authentication works or not.

Comment: One thing very strange is that when I check HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated, I find that it is True.  Meaning that IIS has already authenticated the user.  Somehow User.Identity.Name is not accessible.

Comment: I find that WebService1 can find the username from HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name. That is despite the fact that WebService1 still cannot get access to User.Identity.  I will still try to figure out why User.Identity is not available.  If I cannot figure this out, I will get the username from HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name as a perfectly fine workaround.

Comment: Have you found the reason why WebService1 cannot get access to User.Identity? Any progress on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I still cannot figure out why WebService1 cannot get access to User.Identity.  Just a moment ago, I have tried to use "Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)" for the IIS server in Active Directory.  But this doesn't make any difference.  That idea "looks" very promising though.  Unless there is another promising idea comes along, I think I will stick with the workable alternative -- that is to use HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name instead of User.Identity.Name.